# CSS issues with table layouts

Tags: php, jquery, css, forms

I created a form to create a user account on my system.
Below the form, I used a table which has two functions:

- Deleting one row on the table, which also delete the data in the database
- Modifying user account information using the table

The 2 forms work fine, excepted that I cannot tell to my table to stay below the first form with a fixed size.

I'm new in php, css and jquery, but at this point I'm totally stuck.

Could you have a look at my (long) code?

Fiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/C7Ryz/

**HTML generated**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Manage customer</title>
<link href="styleRegister.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="styleShowRemove.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Jqueryset/jquery/css/overcast/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Jqueryset/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Jqueryset/DataTables-1.9.4/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Jqueryset/jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready( function () {
                $('#userdata').dataTable( {
                        "bJQueryUI": true,
                        "bStateSave": true,
                        "aLengthMenu": [[1,2,3,4,5,10, 25, 50, -1], [1,2,3,4,5,10, 25, 50, "All"]],
                        "sScrollY": "150px",
                        "sScrollX": "50%"
                } );

                $('a').click(function(){
                        var del_id = $(this).attr('id');
                        var parent = $(this).parent();
                        $.post('deletemember.php', {id:del_id},function(data){
                                parent.slideUp('slow', function() {$(this).closest('tr').remove();});
                        });
                });

                $(".edit_tr").click(function(){
                        var ID=$(this).attr('id');
                        $("#firstname_"+ID).hide();
                        $("#lastname_"+ID).hide();
                        $("#email_"+ID).hide();
                        $("#login_"+ID).hide();
            $("#passwd_"+ID).hide();
                        $("#grp_"+ID).hide();
                        $("#firstname_input_"+ID).show();
                        $("#lastname_input_"+ID).show();
                        $("#email_input_"+ID).show();
                        $("#login_input_"+ID).show();
            $("#passwd_input_"+ID).show();
                        $("#grp_input_"+ID).show();
                }).change(function(){
                        var ID=$(this).attr('id');
                        var firstname=$("#firstname_input_"+ID).val();
                        var lastname=$("#lastname_input_"+ID).val();
                        var email=$("#email_input_"+ID).val();
                        var login=$("#login_input_"+ID).val();
            var passwd=$("#passwd_input_"+ID).val();
                        var grp=$("#grp_input_"+ID).val();
                        var dataString = 'id='+ ID +'&firstname=' + firstname + '&lastname=' + lastname + '&email=' + email + '&login=' + login + '&passwd=' + passwd + '&grp=' + grp;
alert(dataString);
                        $("#grp_"+ID).html('<img src="images/load.gif" />'); // Loading image
                        if(firstname.length>0 && lastname.length>0 && email.length>0 && login.length>0 && ((passwd.length>7 && passwd.length<21) || passwd.length<1)) {
alert('ICI');
                                $.ajax({
                                        type: "POST",
                                        url: "table_ajax_showremove.php",
                                        data: dataString,
                                        cache: false,
                                        success: function(html){
                                                $("#firstname_"+ID).html(firstname);
                                                $("#lastname_"+ID).html(lastname);
                                                $("#email_"+ID).html(email);
                                                $("#login_"+ID).html(login);
                        $("#passwd_"+ID).html(passwd);
                                                $("#grp_"+ID).html(grp);
                                        }
                                });

                        }else{
                        var errormsg="";
                                if (firstname.length<1){
                                        errormsg+='Error in Firstname\n';
                                }
                                if (lastname.length<1){
                                        errormsg+='Error in Lastname\n';
                                }
                                if (email.length<1){
                                        errormsg+='Error in Email\n';
                                }
                                if (login.length<1){
                                        errormsg+='Error in Login\n';
                                }
                                if (passwd.length<8 || passwd.length>20){
                                        errormsg+='Error in Password (8-20 length)\n';
                                }
                if (grp.length<1 || grp == 'Select a group'){
                    errormsg+='Not a group valid\n';
                }

                                alert(errormsg);
                        }
                });
                // Edit input box click action
                $(".editbox").mouseup(function(){
                        return false
                });
                // Outside click action
                $(document).mouseup(function(){
                        $(".editbox").hide();
                        $(".text").show();
                });

        } );
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="registeruser"><form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" method="post" action="register-exec.php">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Register</legend>
        <label for="fname">First Name</label>
        <input name="fname" type="text" id="fname" maxlength="20" value="" />
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
        <input name="lname" type="text" id="lname" maxlength="20" value="" />
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input name="email" type="text" id="email" maxlength="30" value="" />
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <label for="login">Login</label>
        <input name="login" type="text" id="login" maxlength="10" value="" />
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input name="password" type="password" id="password" maxlength="20" value="" />
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <label for="cpassword">Confirm Password</label>
        <input name="cpassword" type="password" id="cpassword" maxlength="20" value="" />
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <label for="group">Group</label><select name="group"><option selected="selected" value="Select a group">Select a group</option><OPTION value="ADMIN">ADMIN</OPTION><OPTION value="CC">CC</OPTION><OPTION value="CI">CI</OPTION><OPTION value="CL">CL</OPTION><OPTION value="EC">EC</OPTION><OPTION value="ECI">ECI</OPTION><OPTION value="IT">IT</OPTION><OPTION value="JR">JR</OPTION><OPTION value="LI">LI</OPTION><OPTION value="SN">SN</OPTION></SELECT><div class="clear"></div>
        <input type="submit" style="margin: 0px 0 0 287px;" class="button" name="commit" value="Register" />
        <BR>
          </fielset>
    </form>
    <CENTER><a href="index.php">Return to the Main Page</a> | <a href="logout.php">Logout</a></CENTER>
    <BR>
    </div>
<div id=userdatas><fieldset><form style="width: 100%"><CENTER><table id="userdataa" class="tablesorter" border="1"><thead><tr><th><center>Delete</center></th><th>Firstname</th><th>Lastname</th><th>Email</th><th>Login</th><th>Password</th><th>Group</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr id="1" class="edit_tr">
                        <td class="edit_td">
                                <center>
                                        <a href="javascript:return(0);" id="1">
                                                <img src="images/remove.png" height="12px" width="12px"/>
                                        </a>
                                </center>
                        </td>
                        <td class="edit_td">
                                <span id="firstname_1" class="text">
                                </span>
                                <input type="text" value="Jere" class="editbox" id="firstname_input_1" /&gt;
                        </td>
                        <td class="edit_td">
                                <span id="lastname_1" class="text">
                                </span>
                                <input type="text" value="Dan" class="editbox" id="lastname_input_1"
                        </td>
                        <td class="edit_td">
                                <span id="email_1" class="text">
                                </span>
                                <input type="text" value="jere.d@ext" class="editbox" id="email_input_1"
                        </td>
                        <td class="edit_td">
                                <span id="login_1" class="text">
                                </span>
                                <input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="danneje" class="editbox" id="login_input_1"
                        </td>
                        <td class="edit_td">
                                <span id="passwd_1" class="text">
                                </span>
                                <input type="password" maxlength="20" value="" class="editbox" id="passwd_input_1"
                        </td>
                        <td class="edit_td\>
                                <span id="grp_1" class="text">
                                </span>
                <select name="group" id="grp_input_1" class="editbox"><OPTION value="ADMIN">ADMIN</OPTION><OPTION value="C2SIS">C2SIS</OPTION><OPTION value="CITIS">CITIS</OPTION><OPTION value="CLIMA">CLIMA</OPTION><OPTION value="ECAS">ECAS</OPTION><OPTION value="ECI">ECI</OPTION><OPTION value="ITIC">ITIC</OPTION><OPTION value="JRC">JRC</OPTION><OPTION value="LISO">LISO</OPTION><OPTION value="SNET">SNET</OPTION></SELECT> 
                        </td>
                     </tr><tr id="32" class="edit_tr">
                        <td class="edit_td">
                                <center>
                                        <a href="javascript:return(0);" id="32">
                                                <img src="images/remove.png" height="12px" width="12px"/>
                                        </a>
                                </center>
                        </td>
                        <td class="edit_td">
                                <span id="firstname_32" class="text">
                                </span>
                                <input type="text" value="rikitou" class="editbox" id="firstname_input_32" /&gt;
                        </td>
                        <td class="edit_td">
                                <span id="lastname_32" class="text">
                                </span>
                                <input type="text" value="riki" class="editbox" id="lastname_input_32"
                        </td>
                        <td class="edit_td">
                                <span id="email_32" class="text">
                                </span>
                                <input type="text" value="roo@ro.fr" class="editbox" id="email_input_32"
                        </td>
                        <td class="edit_td">
                                <span id="login_32" class="text">
                                </span>
                                <input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="roro" class="editbox" id="login_input_32"
                        </td>
                        <td class="edit_td">
                                <span id="passwd_32" class="text">
                                </span>
                                <input type="password" maxlength="20" value="" class="editbox" id="passwd_input_32"
                        </td>
                        <td class="edit_td\>
                                <span id="grp_32" class="text">
                                </span>
                <select name="group" id="grp_input_32" class="editbox"><OPTION value="ADMIN">ADMIN</OPTION><OPTION value="C2SIS">C2SIS</OPTION><OPTION value="CITIS">CITIS</OPTION><OPTION value="CLIMA">CLIMA</OPTION><OPTION value="ECAS">ECAS</OPTION><OPTION value="ECI">ECI</OPTION><OPTION value="ITIC">ITIC</OPTION><OPTION value="JRC">JRC</OPTION><OPTION value="LISO">LISO</OPTION><OPTION value="SNET">SNET</OPTION></SELECT>    
                        </td>
                     </tr><tr id="2" class="edit_tr">
                        <td class="edit_td">
                                <center>
                                        <a href="javascript:return(0);" id="2">
                                                <img src="images/remove.png" height="12px" width="12px"/>
                                        </a>
                                </center>
                        </td>
                        <td class="edit_td">
                                <span id="firstname_2" class="text">
                                </span>
                                <input type="text" value="Christoph" class="editbox" id="firstname_input_2" /&gt;
                        </td>
                        <td class="edit_td">
                                <span id="lastname_2" class="text">
                                </span>
                                <input type="text" value="Rosen" class="editbox" id="lastname_input_2"
                        </td>
                        <td class="edit_td">
                                <span id="email_2" class="text">
                                </span>
                                <input type="text" value="christophe.rosen@ext.fr" class="editbox" id="email_input_2"
                        </td>
                        <td class="edit_td">
                                <span id="login_2" class="text">
                                </span>
                                <input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="rozench" class="editbox" id="login_input_2"
                        </td>
                        <td class="edit_td">
                                <span id="passwd_2" class="text">
                                </span>
                                <input type="password" maxlength="20" value="" class="editbox" id="passwd_input_2"
                        </td>
                        <td class="edit_td\>
                                <span id="grp_2" class="text">
                                </span>
                <select name="group" id="grp_input_2" class="editbox"><OPTION value="ADMIN">ADMIN</OPTION><OPTION value="C2SIS">C2SIS</OPTION><OPTION selected="selected" value="CITIS">CITIS</OPTION><OPTION value="CLIMA">CLIMA</OPTION><OPTION value="ECAS">ECAS</OPTION><OPTION value="ECI">ECI</OPTION><OPTION value="ITIC">ITIC</OPTION><OPTION value="JRC">JRC</OPTION><OPTION value="LISO">LISO</OPTION><OPTION value="SNET">SNET</OPTION></SELECT> 
                        </td>
                     </tr><tr id="25" class="edit_tr">
                        <td class="edit_td">
                                <center>
                                        <a href="javascript:return(0);" id="25">
                                                <img src="images/remove.png" height="12px" width="12px"/>
                                        </a>
                                </center>
                        </td>
                        <td class="edit_td">
                                <span id="firstname_25" class="text">
                                </span>
                                <input type="text" value="Michael" class="editbox" id="firstname_input_25" /&gt;
                        </td>
                        <td class="edit_td">
                                <span id="lastname_25" class="text">
                                </span>
                                <input type="text" value="Schle" class="editbox" id="lastname_input_25"
                        </td>
                        <td class="edit_td">
                                <span id="email_25" class="text">
                                </span>
                                <input type="text" value="michael.schle@a.fr" class="editbox" id="email_input_25"
                        </td>
                        <td class="edit_td">
                                <span id="login_25" class="text">
                                </span>
                                <input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="schleml" class="editbox" id="login_input_25"
                        </td>
                        <td class="edit_td">
                                <span id="passwd_25" class="text">
                                </span>
                                <input type="password" maxlength="20" value="" class="editbox" id="passwd_input_25"
                        </td>
                        <td class="edit_td\>
                                <span id="grp_25" class="text">
                                </span>
                <select name="group" id="grp_input_25" class="editbox"><OPTION value="ADMIN">ADMIN</OPTION><OPTION value="C2SIS">C2SIS</OPTION><OPTION value="CITIS">CITIS</OPTION><OPTION value="CLIMA">CLIMA</OPTION><OPTION value="ECAS">ECAS</OPTION><OPTION value="ECI">ECI</OPTION><OPTION value="ITIC">ITIC</OPTION><OPTION value="JRC">JRC</OPTION><OPTION value="LISO">LISO</OPTION><OPTION selected="selected" value="SNET">SNET</OPTION></SELECT>    
                        </td>
                     </tr></tbody></table></CENTER></form></fieldset></div></body></html>
```

**PHP FORM**

```
<?php
require_once('auth.php');
?>

<?php
//  session_start();
require 'config.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Manage customer</title>
<link href="styleRegister.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="styleShowRemove.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Jqueryset/jquery/css/overcast/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Jqueryset/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Jqueryset/DataTables-1.9.4/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Jqueryset/jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready( function () {
                $('#userdata').dataTable( {
                        "bJQueryUI": true,
                        "bStateSave": true,
                        "aLengthMenu": [[1,2,3,4,5,10, 25, 50, -1], [1,2,3,4,5,10, 25, 50, "All"]],
                        "sScrollY": "150px",
                        "sScrollX": "50%"
                } );

                $('a').click(function(){
                        var del_id = $(this).attr('id');
                        var parent = $(this).parent();
                        $.post('deletemember.php', {id:del_id},function(data){
                                parent.slideUp('slow', function() {$(this).closest('tr').remove();});
                        });
                });

                $(".edit_tr").click(function(){
                        var ID=$(this).attr('id');
                        $("#firstname_"+ID).hide();
                        $("#lastname_"+ID).hide();
                        $("#email_"+ID).hide();
                        $("#login_"+ID).hide();
            $("#passwd_"+ID).hide();
                        $("#grp_"+ID).hide();
                        $("#firstname_input_"+ID).show();
                        $("#lastname_input_"+ID).show();
                        $("#email_input_"+ID).show();
                        $("#login_input_"+ID).show();
            $("#passwd_input_"+ID).show();
                        $("#grp_input_"+ID).show();
                }).change(function(){
                        var ID=$(this).attr('id');
                        var firstname=$("#firstname_input_"+ID).val();
                        var lastname=$("#lastname_input_"+ID).val();
                        var email=$("#email_input_"+ID).val();
                        var login=$("#login_input_"+ID).val();
            var passwd=$("#passwd_input_"+ID).val();
                        var grp=$("#grp_input_"+ID).val();
                        var dataString = 'id='+ ID +'&firstname=' + firstname + '&lastname=' + lastname + '&email=' + email + '&login=' + login + '&passwd=' + passwd + '&grp=' + grp;
alert(dataString);
                        $("#grp_"+ID).html('<img src="images/load.gif" />'); // Loading image
                        if(firstname.length>0 && lastname.length>0 && email.length>0 && login.length>0 && ((passwd.length>7 && passwd.length<21) || passwd.length<1)) {
alert('ICI');
                                $.ajax({
                                        type: "POST",
                                        url: "table_ajax_showremove.php",
                                        data: dataString,
                                        cache: false,
                                        success: function(html){
                                                $("#firstname_"+ID).html(firstname);
                                                $("#lastname_"+ID).html(lastname);
                                                $("#email_"+ID).html(email);
                                                $("#login_"+ID).html(login);
                        $("#passwd_"+ID).html(passwd);
                                                $("#grp_"+ID).html(grp);
                                        }
                                });

                        }else{
                        var errormsg="";
                                if (firstname.length<1){
                                        errormsg+='Error in Firstname\n';
                                }
                                if (lastname.length<1){
                                        errormsg+='Error in Lastname\n';
                                }
                                if (email.length<1){
                                        errormsg+='Error in Email\n';
                                }
                                if (login.length<1){
                                        errormsg+='Error in Login\n';
                                }
                                if (passwd.length<8 || passwd.length>20){
                                        errormsg+='Error in Password (8-20 length)\n';
                                }
                if (grp.length<1 || grp == 'Select a group'){
                    errormsg+='Not a group valid\n';
                }

                                alert(errormsg);
                        }
                });
                // Edit input box click action
                $(".editbox").mouseup(function(){
                        return false
                });
                // Outside click action
                $(document).mouseup(function(){
                        $(".editbox").hide();
                        $(".text").show();
                });

        } );
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php

    if( isset($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) && is_array($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) && count($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) >0 ) {
        echo '<ul class="err">';
        $allerror="";
        foreach($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] as $msg) {
            list($before, $after) = explode(':', $msg, 2);

            if ($before == "fname"){
                $fname = $after;
            }else if ($before == "lname"){
                $lname = $after;
            }else if ($before == "email"){
                $email = $after;
            }else if ($before == "login"){
                $login = $after;
            }else if ($before == "group"){
                $group = $after;
            }else{
                $allerror=$allerror."<li>$msg</li>"; 
            }
        }
        echo '</ul>';
        unset($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']);
    }

?>
<?php

if ($currentgroup == ""){

$combobox = "SELECT name from Arc_Customer ORDER BY name";
$reqcbb = mysql_query($combobox) or die('Erreur SQL !<br>'.$sql.'<br>'.mysql_error());

    print '<div id="registeruser"><form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" method="post" action="register-exec.php">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Register</legend>
        <label for="fname">First Name</label>
        <input name="fname" type="text" id="fname" maxlength="20" value="'.$fname.'" />
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
        <input name="lname" type="text" id="lname" maxlength="20" value="'.$lname.'" />
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input name="email" type="text" id="email" maxlength="30" value="'.$email.'" />
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <label for="login">Login</label>
        <input name="login" type="text" id="login" maxlength="10" value="'.$login.'" />
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input name="password" type="password" id="password" maxlength="20" value="'.$password.'" />
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <label for="cpassword">Confirm Password</label>
        <input name="cpassword" type="password" id="cpassword" maxlength="20" value="'.$cpassword.'" />
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <label for="group">Group</label><select name="group">';

        if ($group == ""){
            echo "<option selected=\"selected\" value=\"Select a group\">Select a group</option>";
        }else{
            echo "<option value=\"Select a group\">Select a group</option>";
        } 
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($reqcbb)){
            $cbbname = $row["name"];
            if ($group == "$cbbname"){
                echo "<OPTION selected=\"selected\" value=\"$cbbname\">$cbbname</OPTION>";
            }else{
                echo "<OPTION value=\"$cbbname\">$cbbname</OPTION>";
            }
        }
        print '</SELECT><div class="clear"></div>
        <input type="submit" style="margin: 0px 0 0 287px;" class="button" name="commit" value="Register" />
        '.$allerror.'<BR>
          </fielset>
    </form>
    <CENTER><a href="index.php">Return to the Main Page</a> | <a href="logout.php">Logout</a></CENTER>
    <BR>
    </div>';
}else{
    header("location: login-form.php?id=not");
        exit();

}
?>

<?php

$userdata = "SELECT member_id, firstname, lastname, email, login, grp FROM members ORDER BY lastname";
$requserdata = mysql_query($userdata) or die('Erreur SQL !<br>'.$sql.'<br>'.mysql_error());

echo '<div id=userdatas><fieldset><form style="width: 100%">';

//SEARCH FOR WHICH REASON WE CANNOT RESIZE THE TABLE ==> CHANGE id="userdataa" to id="userdata"
echo '<CENTER><table id="userdataa" class="tablesorter" border="1"><thead><tr><th><center>Delete</center></th><th>Firstname</th><th>Lastname</th><th>Email</th><th>Login</th><th>Password</th><th>Group</th></tr></thead><tbody>';

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($requserdata)){
                $memberid=$row[0];
                $firstname=$row[1];
                $lastname=$row[2];
                $email=$row[3];
                $login=$row[4];
                $grp=$row[5];
        $passwd="";

                echo "<tr id=\"$memberid\" class=\"edit_tr\">
                        <td class=\"edit_td\">
                                <center>
                                        <a href=\"javascript:return(0);\" id=\"{$memberid}\">
                                                <img src=\"images/remove.png\" height=\"12px\" width=\"12px\"/>
                                        </a>
                                </center>
                        </td>
                        <td class=\"edit_td\">
                                <span id=\"firstname_$memberid\" class=\"text\">
                                </span>
                                <input type=\"text\" value=\"$firstname\" class=\"editbox\" id=\"firstname_input_$memberid\" /&gt;
                        </td>
                        <td class=\"edit_td\">
                                <span id=\"lastname_$memberid\" class=\"text\">
                                </span>
                                <input type=\"text\" value=\"$lastname\" class=\"editbox\" id=\"lastname_input_$memberid\"
                        </td>
                        <td class=\"edit_td\">
                                <span id=\"email_$memberid\" class=\"text\">
                                </span>
                                <input type=\"text\" value=\"$email\" class=\"editbox\" id=\"email_input_$memberid\"
                        </td>
                        <td class=\"edit_td\">
                                <span id=\"login_$memberid\" class=\"text\">
                                </span>
                                <input type=\"text\" disabled=\"disabled\" value=\"$login\" class=\"editbox\" id=\"login_input_$memberid\"
                        </td>
                        <td class=\"edit_td\">
                                <span id=\"passwd_$memberid\" class=\"text\">
                                </span>
                                <input type=\"password\" maxlength=\"20\" value=\"$passwd\" class=\"editbox\" id=\"passwd_input_$memberid\"
                        </td>
                        <td class=\"edit_td\>
                                <span id=\"grp_$memberid\" class=\"text\">
                                </span>
                <select name=\"group\" id=\"grp_input_$memberid\" class=\"editbox\">";

                $combobox = "SELECT name from Arc_Customer ORDER BY name";
                $reqcbb = mysql_query($combobox) or die('Erreur SQL !<br>'.$sql.'<br>'.mysql_error());

                        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($reqcbb)){
                                $cbbname = $row["name"];
                                if ($grp == "$cbbname"){
                                        echo "<OPTION selected=\"selected\" value=\"$cbbname\">$cbbname</OPTION>";
                                }else{
                                        echo "<OPTION value=\"$cbbname\">$cbbname</OPTION>";
                                }
                        }
                        print "</SELECT>    
                        </td>
                     </tr>";
        }

echo '</tbody></table></CENTER></form></fieldset></div></body></html>';
?>
```

**CSS for the first FORM**

```
*{ 
    margin: 0px; 
    padding: 0;
}

body{ 
    font-family: Georgia, 
    serif; 
    background: url(images/member-page-bg.jpg) top center no-repeat #c4c4c4;
    color: #3a3a3a;  
}

.clear{
    clear: both; 
}

form{ 
    width: 406px; 
    margin: 170px auto 0; 
}

legend{ 
    display: none;
}

fieldset{ 
    border: 0;
}

label{ 
    width: 150px; 
    text-align: right; 
    float: left; margin: 0 10px 0 0; 
    padding: 9px 0 0 0; 
    font-size: 16px; 
}

input{ 
    width: 220px;
    display: block;
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #3a3a3a; 
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
}

select{
        width: 220px;
        display: block;
        padding: 4px;
        margin: 0 0 10px 0;
        font-size: 18px;
        color: #3a3a3a;
        font-family: Georgia, serif;
}

.button{
    background: url(images/button-bg.png) repeat-x top center;
    border: 1px solid #999;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
    padding: 5px;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 13px;
    width: 70px;
}

.button:hover { 
    background: white; 
    color: black; 
}
```

**CSS for the TABLE**

```
body
{
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
}
.editbox
{
display:none
}
td
{
padding:5px;
}
.editbox
{
font-size:14px;
width:270px;
background-color:#ffffcc;
border:solid 1px #000;
padding:4px;
}
//.edit_tr:hover
//{
//background:url(images/edit.gif) right no-repeat #80C8E5;
//cursor:pointer;
//}
```

Comment: OP is obviously new and English is probably not his primary language.  If you are going to down vote him at least tell him why.

Comment: Please post the HTML output of the PHP instead of the PHP.

Comment: Your code is too much. It's good idea to create a [FIDDLE](http://www.jsfiddle.net/) by the `output` of your PHP code. Then, debugging will be possible.

Comment: with that much code, you're unlikely to get much help. try reducing the problem down to the smallest amount of code that can demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot into the blue: When you are talking about "fixed size", have you tried table-layout:fixed; for your table?

And then, I don't see where you set the width of the table or columns at all.

HTML output would help a lot indeed ...

Comment: Sorry if i made some mistake for my first post. I'll try to do my best an another time. I'll post the HTML code tomorrow as I don't have access to my code now. The php part works fine (I think) as I obtain that I want (populate my database, remove data and change data of the databse). The problem is the 'display" of the page. I don't understand the strange behavior of the table, each table I click outside the table or the forme, the table is re-sized. But I'll copy/paste the HTML code tomorrow. Once time, sorry if i don't explain correctly.

Comment: When you click, and that click causes a change of display, does the page reload? If it does, it could be the php that changes something in html or css, otherwise it would likely be the js. Anyway, it would be best to see the before and after of your html/css. Ideally a live site or fiddle, as suggested by Mojtaba.

Comment: Hello, I've added the HTML code and also the Fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/C7Ryz/ But it seems that on fiddle the jquery script doesnt work on the table :-/ but in reality in my environment it works.

Comment: After some test, it's seems that the problem come from this function // Outside click action
                $(document).mouseup(function(){
                        $(".editbox").hide(); I've commented the function and now, the table stay in the right place, exepted that when the page is load, the table is empty. I've a to click on the table to see the content :-/
                        $(".text").show();
                });

Comment: Well, I can't see anything happening in the fiddle. Anyway, if the table moves up when you hide the ".editbox", perhaps it's that box that gives the column width and when it's gone it collapses. Why not assign fixed widths? And the table shouldn't move up when it's width changes. Maybe add a <div class="clr"></div> before the table? But from the fiddle, I see no reason why it should move in the first place. It's all blocks and no float ...

Answer (score 0):

So definitively the problem comes from Jquery javascript :-p

I've modified the 2 last function

```
            // Edit input box click action
            $(".editbox").mouseup(function(){
                    return false;
            });
            // Outside click action
            $(document).mouseup(function(){
                    $(".editbox").show(); // I've change .hide to .show
                    $(".text").show();
            });
```

Now, Excepted that I've to click on the table, I don't have any problem to select and modify element on the tale.

I'm searching now how to see the filled table diectly when the page is load. I don't want to click the table to see the content f the table :-p

Hope I'll find the solution this morning. Then this week end I'll buy a book and study php, css and Jquery/javasript :-)

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for my page :-)

I've just removed the function

```
        // Outside click action
        $(document).mouseup(function(){
                $(".editbox").show(); // I've change .hide to .show
                $(".text").show();
        });
```

And kept the body,

```
                $(".editbox").show(); // I've change .hide to .show
                $(".text").show();
```

And now the page works fine.

I now that maybe it's not the correct way, and that probably the code should be reviewved. But for now I think I can close this post.

For for your help!